# Eclipse plugin RCP question

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am creating new Eclipse RCP application. I used "Hello RCP" as template project to create a new project. It works fine. Then I tried adding new menu. I used two extension points "org.eclipse.ui.commands" and "org.eclipse.ui.menu". I created handler class and also defined the menucontribution location uri(). But my menu is not showing up. I strongly suspect my location uri is wrong. But I dont know how to correct it. I have pasted my plugin.xml contents here. Let me know if anyone has a solution. I am following the steps given here http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/Add_Menu_to_RCP_Application

Comment: <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">                       Sorry I could not paste my full plugin.xml file

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your plugin.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApplicationActionbarAdvisor class to define menus and commands for toolbar as well as menubar.
Firstly you have to declare the commands you want to add in your app like below:

`private IWorkbenchAction newAction`

Then with the help of ActionFactory class, you have to define the commands in makeActions() method like below:

```
newAction = ActionFactory.NEW_WIZARD_DROP_DOWN.create(window);
    register(newAction);
    newAction.setText("New");
```

Now, after declaration you have to add the commands in menus by using fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) method :

```
MenuManager filemenu = new MenuManager("&File", "file");
    filemenu.add(newAction);
```

and if you want to add this command in toolbar, then you have to use following method:

`protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
        IToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(coolBar.getStyle());
        coolBar.add(toolbar);
        toolbar.add(newAction);`

Sometimes, you have to use IContributionIem class for declaring commands because all the commands are not in IWorkbenchAction class.

Note: If you are using iContributionItem class then declaration and defination code will be replaced as follws:

`IContributionItem show_view;`

`show_view = ContributionItemFactory.VIEWS_SHORTLIST.create(window);`

and rest will be same.

Comment: I havent explored this way of menu addition. I have done it only through plugin.xml. I will check this. Thanks